# Whats wrong with my code for finding the roots of the quadratic equation?

Tags: c

If the quadratic equation is written as

> ax^2 + bx + c=0

And my code is written as this....

I used temp to get the value of the equation under the square roots.

> root1 = [-b + [(b^2 - (4*a*c)]^(1/2) ] / 2*a
>
> root2 = [-b - [(b^2 - (4*a*c)]^(1/2) ] / 2*a

```
//Program for finding the roots of Quadratic equations
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
    float a,b,c,temp,root1,root2  ;    //aloting the values

    printf(“Finding the roots of variable \n Enter the values of a,b,c ”)  ;
    scanf(“%f,%f,%f”,&a,&b,&c ) ;      //Getting the values of a,b and c

    temp=b*b –(4*a*c) ;                //used in the equation

    if (a!=0 && temp>=0)               //using the condition
    {
        root1 = (-b + sqrt(temp))/a*2 ;
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(temp))/a*2 ;

        printf(“Roots of the equation are %f and %f”, &root1,&root2) ;
    }
    else 
        printf(“There is no real value  of  roots of the given equation ”) ;
}
```

Comment: Should be `/ (a*2)`

Comment: should be `if (scanf("%f,%f,%f", &a, &b, &c) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: `%f` - represents `float`, not *address of* `float`...

Comment: Printing with `"%e"` or `"%g"` is more informative here, in general,  than `"%f"`.

Comment: Note: `printf(“Roots of the equation are %f and %f”,...` is not valid C. Use `"`, not smart quotes like `“`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `(..)`, should be

```
    root1 = (-b + sqrt(temp)) / (a * 2);

    root2 = (-b - sqrt(temp)) / (a * 2);
```

Technically, if `a == 0` real (not complex) roots are *quite possible*, e.g. `0 * x**2 + 3 * x = 6`. So

```
 if (a != 0) {
   if (temp >= 0) {
     ...
   }
   else /* quadratic equation with complex roots only */
     printf(“There is no real value of roots of the given equation”);
 }
 else if (b != 0) {  /* 0 * x**2 + b * x + c = 0 */
   /* the only root */
   float root = -c / b;

   printf(“Root of the equation is %f”, &root);
 }
 else if (c != 0) /* 0 * x**2 + 0 * x + c = 0 */
   printf(“No roots”);
 else             /* 0 * x**2 + 0 * x + 0 = 0 */
   printf(“Arbitrary number is a root”);
```

Or, if you don't want to solve for *all possible cases*

```
 if (a != 0) {
   if (temp >= 0) {
     ...
   }
   else /* quadratic equation with complex roots only */
     printf(“There is no real value of roots of the given equation”);
 }
 else 
   printf(“The equation is not quadratic one”);
```

Comment: but if a =0 then the given equation won't be a quadratic equation and hence it will become a linear equation

Comment: @Himanshu Kurzekar: yes, with `a = 0` the equation is *not quadratic* (it *can* be *linear one*); however, we can't say "There is *no real value  of  roots* of the given equation " when `a = 0`.

Comment: @Alex Lop.: I'm sorry for the typo; copy + paste is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious problems.

First

> ```
> root1 = (-b + sqrt(temp))/a*2;
> ```

is equivalent, due to rules of operator precedence, to  (note where I've added parentheses).

```
root1 = ((-b + sqrt(temp))/a)*2;
```

which is wrong.  It should be something like

```
root1 = (-b + sqrt(temp))/(a*2) ;
```

A similar comment applies for the calculation of `root2`.

Second, the statement

> ```
> printf(“Roots of the equation are %f and %f”, &root1,&root2);
> ```

attempts to print the addresses of `root1` and `root2` (not the values of `root1` and `root2`).    That actually causes undefined behaviour.   You need to remove the `&`s (which are required to use `scanf()` correctly, but not `printf()`).

There are some other flaws in your code (bad technique) but I won't deal with those.